# Use the HTML <img> tag as a background image instead of the CSS background-image property?

Tags: html, css, image

I need to use the html `<img>` tag as a background image for a `<div>`. I will then be placing a `<p>` of content over this. I've tried this but cant seem to get them to display correctly. I've used position relative, margin with negative values.

Any suggestions or point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

```html
<div>

  <img src="http://www.shiaupload.ir/images/77810787432153420049.png" />

  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Why is `background image` not suitable?

Comment: You want to set  <img> as background for parent <div>?

Comment: Yes, as I'm styling an email, the outlook client doesn't like the background-image property.

Comment: @dognose The main reason someone would want to do this is if the background image is part of the site's content, and isn't there purely for styling purposes.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To make an almost perfectly duplicate of the features used for background-image, we've to consider the features of the `img` include:

- It doesn't have any pointer events.
- It's rendered at least one layer below the `div`.

The result would be something like this:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

p {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/720x480/ddd/007" />
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
    typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
    printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
    specimen book
  </p>
</div>
```

You might modify the width and height to your needs.

Comment: The `img` could also use `object-fit: cover;` to replicate a background image with `background-size: cover;`.

Comment: you should use `min-width` and `min-height` 100%. If you use `width` and `height` the image will stretch on resize

Comment: You can play with the absolute positioning properties `top`, `right`, `bottom`, `left`. In combination with setting the `min-width` and `max-width` to `100%` instead of the `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 5):

In the future this may be possible with the new css element() function:

`background-image: element(img_element_id)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/element