# html <img> tag instead of css background-image

Tags: html, css

I've currently got a background properly working using the css `background-image` property. But instead I would like to use the html `<img>` tag. With the `background-image` property I have:

```
<section className="banner">
    <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper">
            <p>bla bla content, buttons, etc.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

.banner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 428px;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url("/image.jpg");
}
```

I've tried using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31267758) as a guide, to create the content below:

```
<section className="banner">
    <img
        alt=""
        src={"/image.jpg"}
    />
    <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper">
            <p>bla bla content, buttons, etc.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

.banner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    
    height: 528px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
    background-color: #000;

    .img {
        position: absolute;
        object-fit: cover;
        min-width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
}
```

However, this does not display the content in the wrapper and part of the right side of the image isn't displayed. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Notice that the answer in the other question has `img {` outside of `.banner-sectiom {`

Comment: Also, remove the period from `.img {`

Comment: The fact that I have `img {` inside of `.banner {` is just part of the css library I use, so that's correct. The period from `.img {` should indeed not be there. I have removed it. The result: it shows up correctly ... except... the background-color of the banner section "overwrites" the image. If I give the image a higher `z-index`, the image is displayed but "overwrites" the wrapper content"... If I remove the `background-color` from the `banner` it still displays the section with a white color, thereby not displaying the image (that I think is then underneath that section)..

Comment: Give the image a z-index and give everything else a higher index.

Comment: Yess! Adding a `z-index: 0;` for the `.banner` did the trick! Thanks, if you'll add it as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the `img` a `z-index` and everything else a higher `z-index`.

```
img { z-index: -1; }
.banner-options: { z-index: 0 }
```

This will put `img` farther in front, but `.banner-options` even farther.