# How to set a <picture> as the background image for an element?

Tags: html, css

I have a picture element. How do I use it to get the same effect as having `background-image: url("i.jpg");`?

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="i-big.webp"
            media="(min-width: 768px)">
    <source srcset="i-small.webp">
    <img src="i.jpg" alt="Background image"/>
</picture>
```

Comment: give it a negative z-index to move it to the background. Use `position: absolute; inset: 0;`to make it span an entire relative element.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74097622/664456

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the picture element in the same way you are using the background-image. Background-image is related to the background of an element, and can keep the original dimensions (to be repeated or be centered etc) but if you resize your picture element it will just be stretched.