# How to load background images using CSS in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am trying to make a hero image in ExpressJS. However, I have found that I could not load the image via CSS's `background-image`. I attempted to use regular `<img>` tags, but they cause strange formatting and stretch issues ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31267425/use-the-html-img-tag-as-a-background-image-instead-of-the-css-background-image) doesn't work for me). I believe that Express is limiting access to images via CSS, how could I fix this?

(By the way I am using .hbs for render)

This is my code currently:

```css
#hero {
  /* disable-check-5 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("/img/main.jpg");

  height: 60%;

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

#hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
```

and HBS

```
<div id="hero">
  <div id="hero-text">
    <h1>{{hero.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{hero.text}}</p>
    <a href="/bw/sydney">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success">{{hero.button-txt}}</button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have 2 questions ? 1) is this path /img/main.jpg correct? like when you tried using img tag the path was same? 2) did you set public directory to serve static assets like images or style sheet?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra I tried using an IMG tag, (which served the image, with formatting issues) with the same path

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use to tell express to use a directory which will serve your static assets like css, images or javascript. Usually in express world it is called as public directory, so you create image folder in public.

the structure is like **root of project folder -> src, public directory**

In your app.js

```
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname,'./public')
app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))
```

in your HTML file

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url("./img/main.jpg");
```

Note `./public is relative to app.js`